# Problem while truncating double to two decimal places Java

Tags: java

[image: error]

While I'm using truncating in this method, it is somewhere wrong as in picture

```
    public static List<Double> interp(DoubleUnaryOperator f, double l, double u, int n) {
        double d = (u - l)/n;
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>(n);
        double net = f.applyAsDouble(l);
        result.add(net);
        int i = 0;
        while(i+1 < n){

        result.add(Math.floor(f.applyAsDouble(l + d)*100)/100);
        l += d;

        i++;

       }

    return result;
   }
```

Who know how to truncate correclty? P.S. its important for the number be in two decimal places.

Comment: Can you please post the expected and actual output here as text instead of linking an image?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(dblVar);
           df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
 s = df.format(d);
```

and import the class `java.text.DecimalFormat`.